# Republishing maven artifacts fails the build with GitHub Packages

Tags: github, gradle, github-actions, github-package-registry, maven-publish

I have a repository on GitHub that publishes through the maven-publish gradle plugin a few artifacts to a Nexus repository and GitHub Packages (with the help of GitHub Actions). Republishing the maven artifacts fails the build with GitHub Packages because the artifacts can't be republished  with the same version.

For every version there exists a branch e.g. version/X that gets created when a new version
of a software is released. A PR for this branch gets created and then merged into the master branch. The problem is that the branches should publish only once as specific jars are downloaded from a server for that version of the software e.g. 11.1 for version/1 , 17.5 for version/2 etc. A few problems exist:

1. When I push the branch, GitHub actions is triggered, the artifacts get published and the build is green. When I merge the branch into master, the build fails because I can't republish an artifact with the same version to Github Packages (Received status code 409 from server: Conflict). The nexus server is probably configured to ignore it, so it is not a problem.
2. Every artifact is published through a dedicated Gradle task. Let's say task 5 fails, because the download location for the jar has changed or the jar that should be published doesn't exist in the new version. As a result the full build fails. I could make Gradle continue except failing a task, but task 5 maybe has to be published anyways, so I have to manually remove artifacts 1-4 from Github Packages, make the changes and push the branch again. In the worst case, I have to delete 10 artifacts manually.

I know that published artifacts shouldn't be deleted and they should have unique names. Is there a way to deal with both these scenarios anyways (like deleting the artifacts first) or is a unique name for every time the publication is triggered the only solution? I'd really like to avoid that option as there is no reason to publish the exact same artifacts with different suffixes as there is already no correlation between the software version and the name of the artifacts. I also don't want to pollute the nexus server with half published artifacts as people navigate it through the UI and wouldn't know that one set of artifacts were not fully published. Additional information: these artifacts are only published about three times a year. I am mainly concerned by the failing build and the troubles that are theoretically possible when a single branch has to be republished for some reason (e.g. a bug fix version of an old version of the software introduces a new artifact). The publishing process itself could also change, that means that a change to the publishing script also fails the build.